# Let $\operatorname{rad}(I)$ be finitely generated and $I$ an ideal - Prove that $\exists_n (\operatorname{rad}(I))^n\subset I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

The elements of an ideal (which $\operatorname{rad}(I)$ is) taken to the $n$-th power look like this:

$$\left\{\sum _{i=1}^s (a_{i,1}\:\cdot  a_{i,\:n} )\::\:s\:\in \mathbb{N},\:a_{i,j} \text{ are elements of the ideal taken to the $n^\text{th}$ power}\right\}$$

Using this definition for the elements of $\left(\operatorname{rad}(I)\right)^n$, how can I prove this statement?

I know that the best situation would be if I get:

$$\{r_1^n+\cdots+r_s^n\}$$

Then assuming that n is the power so that $r^n\in I$ for any $r\in \operatorname{rad}(I)$, we would have proved it

Comment: hint: let $r_1,\dots,r_k$ be the generators of $\operatorname{rad}(I)$. then, for each $i\leqslant k$, then exists some $n_i$ such that $r_i^{n_i}\in I$. now let $n=\sum_{i\leqslant k}n_i$. can you see why $(\operatorname{rad}(I))^n\subseteq I$?

Comment: See my edits for proper usage in MathJax and LaTeX.

Comment: But then something like $r_1r_2^{n-1}$ will also be an element of $\left(rad\left(I\right)\right)^n$ and this does not necessarily has to be an element of I

Comment: ah, in fact $r_1r_2^{n-1}$ *does* lie in $I$! :) indeed, we have two cases. if $n_1\leqslant 1$, then $r_1\in I$ already, so (by definition of an ideal) $r_2^{n-1}r_1\in I$ too. if $n_1>1$, then $n>1+n_2$, since $n\geqslant n_1+n_2$ by construction. thus $$r_1r_2^{n-1}=(r_1r_2^{n-1-n_2})r^{n_2},$$ and this element does lie in $I$, again by definition of an ideal, since $r^{n_2}\in I$ by construction of the $n_i$

Comment: Ok I think I got it, thanks, if I'd have any more questions I'll write

Comment: my pleasure, happy it helped. :) let me know if you have any further questions!

Comment: Yes, I have one more, but about a different topic in Abstract Algebra